# How to change text in textarea with WebDriver

Tags: java, webdriver, htmlunit

I can not change the text in textarea using WebClient/HtmlUnit/Java. I tried to google it, but with no luck. Can anyone help? There is source code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://some_site.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("niEditor")).sendKeys("some value");
String test = findElement(By.id("niEditor")).getText(); // no changes
```

and the tags in html:

```
<textarea class="tinyMCE newitem2" id="niEditor" name="description"> MANY TEXT </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it (and it works for me)

```
driver.findElement(By.id("niEditor")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("niEditor").sendKeys("data");
```

The first line of code actually shifts the focus to the text area which might be causing the issue for you. Try out this code and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to grab the text, use the following:

```
String test = driver.FindElement(By.Id("niEditor")).GetAttribute("value");
```

This is written in C#, but there should be an equivalent for you in Java

Answer (score 0):

In case of clearing and sending keys does not help:

`webdriver.findElement(<locator of previous element>).sendKeys(Keys.TAB, Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a"), "This text will replace text in textarea");`